# Error with spark Row.fromSeq for a text file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object fixedLength {

  def main(args:Array[String]) {

    def getRow(x : String) : Row={    
    val columnArray = new Array[String](4)
    columnArray(0)=x.substring(0,3)
    columnArray(1)=x.substring(3,13)
    columnArray(2)=x.substring(13,18)
    columnArray(3)=x.substring(18,22)
    Row.fromSeq(columnArray)  
  }

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("ReadingCSV").getOrCreate()


    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FixedLength").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)    
    val fruits = sc.textFile("in/fruits.txt")

    val schemaString = "id,fruitName,isAvailable,unitPrice";
    val fields = schemaString.split(",").map( field => StructField(field,StringType,nullable=true))
    val schema = StructType(fields)

    val df = spark.createDataFrame(fruits.map { x => getRow(x)} , schema)
    df.show() // Error
    println("End of the program")
  }
}
```

I'm getting error in the df.show() command. 
My file content is

```
56 apple     TRUE 0.56
45 pear      FALSE1.34
34 raspberry TRUE 2.43
34 plum      TRUE 1.31
53 cherry    TRUE 1.4 
23 orange    FALSE2.34
56 persimmon FALSE23.2
```

> ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.util.SerializableConfiguration cannot be cast to [B
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:81)

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `rdd` in old way `SparkContext(conf)`

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FixedLength").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)    
val fruits = sc.textFile("in/fruits.txt")
```

whereas you are creating `dataframe` in new way using `SparkSession`

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("ReadingCSV").getOrCreate()
val df = spark.createDataFrame(fruits.map { x => getRow(x)} , schema)
```

Ultimately you are mixing `rdd` created with old `sparkContext` functions with `dataframe` created by using new `sparkSession`.

I would suggest you to use only one way.

I guess thats the reason for the issue

**Update**

doing the following should work for you

```
def getRow(x : String) : Row={    
val columnArray = new Array[String](4)
columnArray(0)=x.substring(0,3)
columnArray(1)=x.substring(3,13)
columnArray(2)=x.substring(13,18)
columnArray(3)=x.substring(18,22)
Row.fromSeq(columnArray)  
}

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("ReadingCSV").getOrCreate()

val fruits = spark.sparkContext.textFile("in/fruits.txt")

val schemaString = "id,fruitName,isAvailable,unitPrice";
val fields = schemaString.split(",").map( field => StructField(field,StringType,nullable=true))
val schema = StructType(fields)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(fruits.map { x => getRow(x)} , schema)
```

Comment: I tried other ways.. but it didn't work. Can you correct the code

Comment: what did you try? When I tried it worked perfectly :) can you update with what you tried and your new error?

Comment: val df = spark.read.schema(schema).load("in/fruits.txt");  this was expecting a parque file, but my file is a text file. sc.textFile() is the only function that I could find which is older form of RDD.. Do we have any option to read just a flat file using Spark session ?.

Comment: val df = spark.sparkContext.textFile("in/fruits.txt"); is reading the file, but I'm not able to parse each line and "map" my schema.